# android app crash at starting intent with onSaveinstanceState

Tags: android, listview, save, instance, state

I have a ListView. The Items of the ListView are saved in a ArrayList called MSGs.
Now i implented onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to my class.

The thing with the orientation change works, but when i click on a item of the ListView the App crash.

I dont know what the problem could be.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inbox);

    //ListView
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {


                try {

                     Intent ii = new Intent(Inbox.this, MSGsOpenMsg.class);
                     ii.putExtra("messageid", m_MSGs.get(position).messageid);
                     ii.putExtra("box", "inbox");
                     startActivityForResult(ii, 0);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
          });

}

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("MSGs", (Serializable)m_MSGs);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        m_MSGs = (ArrayList<MSGs>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("MSGs");
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: The problem occurs when it try to start the Intent =/ But i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

If your ListView class is extending the android api ListActivity, the way I handle clicking or selecting one of the list items is through overriding the onListItemClick method, like so:

```
/**
   * onListItemClick method
   * 
   * This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.
   * 
   * Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call
   * getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data
   * associated with the selected item.
   * 
   * @param ListView
   *          l The ListView where the click happened.
   * @param View
   *          v The view that was clicked within the ListView.
   * @param int position The position of the view in the list.
   * @param long id The row id of the item that was clicked.
   * 
   * @return void
   * 
   */
  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    try {       
      if (this.mListCursor != null) {
        this.mListCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        Intent listItemIntent = new Intent(this, otherAppActivity.class);

        //You can put whatever you want here as an extra
        listItemIntent.putExtra("listItemValue", this.mListCursor
         .getString(this.mListCursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(myDbAdapter.KEY_TABLE_PRIMKEY)));

        startActivity(listItemIntent);
      }// end if (this.mListCursor != null)
    } catch (Exception error) {
      MyErrorLog<Exception> errExcpError = new MyErrorLog<Exception>(this);
      errExcpError.addToLogFile(error,
          "myListView.onListItemSelected", "no prompt");
      errExcpError = null;
    }// end try/catch (Exception error)
  }// end onListItemClick
```

Comment: Nope thats not the problem, the onClick events works, but only when i add the code for instancestatesave it crash